# How to display only contacts with phone number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a recipient picker view. But I want to display only contacts that have a phone number before I pick one.

This is how I get the modal view:

```
-(void)messageWillShowRecipientPicker{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = 
              [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    NSArray *displayedItems = 
                [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber 
                         numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];

    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
    // Show the picker 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release]; 
}
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this out, should work. Might have to tweak it ^-^

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *allContacts = [(NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)autorelease];
    for (int i =0; i < allContacts.count; i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = [allContacts objectAtIndex:i];
        if (person != nil) {
            ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) == 0) {
                CFErrorRef error = nil;
                ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, person, &error);
                NSLog(@"Removing %@",(NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
            }
            CFRelease(phones);
        }
    }
    CFErrorRef saveError = nil;
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &saveError);

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    picker.addressBook = addressBook;

    NSArray *displayedItems = 
    [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber 
                              numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];

    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;

    // Show the picker 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: Won't `ABAddressBookSave()` remove from the main address book databse the contacts that were filtered out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSPredicate` to filter the data, but you may need to make a proxy object to deal with the AddressBook, or a Protocol.

Check out https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper/blob/master/ABContactsHelper.m for an example of a Protocol for AddressBook and Apple's Predicate information here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html and here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Cheers and good luck!  (^_^)